# How to get the unique identifier of a metadata field?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

For example, the [Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm) has the field `applicationVisibilities`, which has the unique value inside `application` (see below). This identifies an application visibility. Another example: `customPermissions` has the unique value "name" per custom permission.

```
<applicationVisibilities>
  <!-- This --><application>standard__AllTabSet</application>
  <default>true</default>
  <visible>true</visible>
</applicationVisibilities>
```

Is it possible to get this information via API (pro grammatically)? I request `Profile.applicationVisibilities` and get `application` back?

Comment: Are you using [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm)? Please edit your question and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what information do you want to get exactly?

Comment: I need to know that the field "application" is the field that contains the primary unique name of that application visibility. Application visibilities is just an example. I'd need that information for arbitrary metadata.

Comment: the thing is that you can't get an information about arbitrary staff with `SetupEntityAccess`, you can only get info for `ApexClass`, `ApexPage`, `ConnectedApplication`, `CustomEntityDefinition`, `TabSet`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to get.

Here is the code to get list of Application Names for particular Profile

```
String profileName = 'System Administrator';
Profile p = [
        SELECT Id
        FROM Profile
        WHERE Name = :profileName
];

List<SetupEntityAccess> setupEntityAccesses = [
        SELECT Id, SetupEntityId
        FROM SetupEntityAccess
        WHERE Parent.ProfileId = :p.Id AND SetupEntityType = 'TabSet'
];

Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
for (SetupEntityAccess setupEntityAccess : setupEntityAccesses) {
    ids.add(setupEntityAccess.SetupEntityId);
};

List<AppMenuItem> menuItems = [
        SELECT Id, Label
        FROM AppMenuItem
        WHERE ApplicationId IN :ids
];

List<String> applicationNames = new List<String>();

for (AppMenuItem appMenuItem : menuItems) {
    applicationNames.add(appMenuItem.Label);
}
```